# Root shell in system filesystem with GRUB

Tags: debian, shell, linux-kernel, grub2, grub

I'm learning about GRUB and, after search for a while, I tried to get a root shell changing the kernel load string:

```
/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-8amd64 root=UUID=e8485edc.... ro single
```

to

```
/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-8amd64 root=UUID=e8485edc.... rw single init=/bin/bash
```

It works and I get a root console. However, The filesystem mounted on "/" directory of this filesystem is not the filesystem mounted on the "original" system. I checked if it is a chroot but it isn't.

Could someone explain what is the filesystem mounted on `/` in this root shell?

How can I access to the original fs? I'm on Debian 7.

**EDIT**

I notice that I get root access to a system filesystem (the fs mounted on the / partition). However, I would like to get into other partitions such as /home.

**Explained**:

I have, for example, 5 partitions (/, /home, /var, /usr, swap). When I do the trick and I get a root shell, I get into / partition, so i'm not able to see what is in home partition. However, fdisk -l command shows all partitions but df -h only shows two fs of two of these partitions (/ and /usr). I would like to see what is in /home partition. What can I do

Comment: Whats your working directory when you get shell access? What is the results when you run `ls`?

Comment: @kemotep is the root directory and if I run `ls` I get all linux directories (/home, /var..)

Comment: @GAD3R I think I don't have explained myself correctly. I have, for example, 5 partitions (/, /home, /var, /usr, swap). When I do the trick and I get a root shell, I get into / partition, so i'm not able to see what is in home partition. However, `fdisk -l` command shows all partitions but `df -h` only shows two fs of two of these partitions (/ and /usr). I would like to see what is in /home partition. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply run

```
mount -a
```

to mount all the filesystems that your system would usually mount (ie. all the entries in `/etc/fstab`)

Comment: Can you believe that I was reloading webpage to say that I found the solution? Yep, that was the issue. I don't knwo why fs weren't mounted but that's it. Thanks!

Comment: @Miguel_sec Wekk, they weren't loaded since that is usually done by your OS's init processes (be they `init.d`, `systemd` or something else entirely), which you overwrote with `init=/bin/bash`.

Comment: Oh wait, thanks! I thought I understand it at 100% but I didn't. That is interesting :) Ty